# CakePHP Database Structure for game with 2 and more players

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have to create a DB for a game and for the active games I need to save 2 user id's from the users table.

Normally I would use the field user_id in my activegames table to have the reference, but how do I do this with 2 users the same time?
Like user_id1 and user_id2?

Keeping the CakePHP database structure along the convention?

Same question regarding the selected weapons for an active game. Just one would be weapon_id but the player can select up to 4 of them?
weapon_id1, weapon_id2, weapon_id3, weapon_id4?

What is here best practice?

I look forward to your answers!
Kind regards!

Comment: Surely the `weapons` belong to the `player`? Therefore `weapon_idx` fields are not needed in an attack table as they can be assigned as `equipped` by the `player`.

Comment: Also, if there are 2 OR MORE players in attack, another table will be needed. Say... `player_to_attack` which would be a 1-n relationship.

Comment: In my case it's a simple 1:1 rel. The active game just contains the 2 players and their selected weapons.

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking in 1-1 relations. Try 1-n relations. A "link" table that contains two columns.  First is game_id, second is player_id.

This table can have any number of rows for one game. Thus no specific number of players.

player table

```
id    name
1     John Doe 
2     jane Doe
```

game table

```
id    title
1     A special game
```

game_players relation table

```
game_id   player_id
1         1
1         2
```

You can do the same with weapons (or anything else)